# Format echo json_encode

Tags: php, json

I would like to format the echo json_encode, the output is currently

```
{"results":{"course":"CC140","books":{"book":[[{"id":"300862","title":"Building object-oriented software","isbn":"0070431965","borrowedcount":"6"}]]}}}
```

Whereas i would like to to output like this:

```
{
    "results": {
        "course": "CC140",
        "books": {
            "book": [
                [
                    {
                        "id": "300862",
                        "title": "Building object-oriented software",
                        "isbn": "0070431965",
                        "borrowedcount": "6"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code that makes the JSON

```
$temp = array();
    foreach ($my_array as $counter => $bc) {
        $temp['id'] = "$id[$counter]";
        $temp['title'] = "$title[$counter]";
        $temp['isbn'] = "$isbn[$counter]";
        $temp['borrowedcount'] = "$borrowedcount[$counter]";
        $t2[] = $temp;
    }

        $data = array(
  "results" => array(
    "course" => "$cc",
    "books" => array(
      "book" =>
      array(  
        $t2
      )
    )
  )
);
    echo json_encode($data);
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated, thanks

Adding this

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

formats the JSON, but the header also outs the entire HTML document

Comment: Why would you ever bother what JSON looks like? Its structure matters, not the way it is formatted...

Comment: probably adding json header will help.

Answer (score 19):

The first piece of advice I'd give is: Don't. JSON is a data format. Deal with it using tools rather then trying to have your server format it.

If you are going to ignore that, then see the manual for the [`json_encode` function](http://php.net/json_encode) where it gives a list of *options* which includes `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` which is described as *Use whitespace in returned data to format it. Available since PHP 5.4.0.*

Thus the steps are:

1. Make sure you are using PHP 5.4.0 or newer
2. `json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Comment: the Pretty Print alone does not out it correctly however adding
header('Content-type: application/json');

before works, but outputs the HTML document with it

Comment: I disagree with your first statement, the fact that JSON is a data format is not a reason to keep it hard to read for humans, as soon as the standard allows such formating, which is the case for JSON.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)` in php 5.4+

In php 5.3 & under that, you could try formatting it with regular expressions, but it's not too safe (or you could use library for encoding json).